# Oculus DK2 + second monitor for displaying DK2 image (but not warped and stereoscopic)

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, oculus-rift

we have the following process/toolchain and would like to have one question answered:

start **Open Broadcaster Software** (mirrors one screen to another screen, in our case **Oculus VR DK2** image to normal monitor) -> start **vorpX** in the mirrored broadcast -> start the game (**rFactor 2**) in the mirrored broadcast.

We now have one stereoscopic image for the VR headset and another stereoscopic image on the normal LCD monitor but want to have **a non-stereoscopic image on the second screen, which is not splitted and warped for an audience** (just raw game image). Is there any way to achieve this?

**OS: Windows 7 Graphics card: Nvidia GTX660**

A possible solution is to cut one image out of the two and unwarp it. How does this work?

This is what I posted as a clarification upon being put on hold on some other site:

There are two display devices connected to the computer (one single graphics card): The Oculus Rift DK2 and an LCD screen. With our current setup/toolchain, we manage to have a mirrored image of what is being displayed in the DK2 on the LCD screen but want to have **a single image there (not splitted)**.

Best regards, Chris

Comment: You appear to have created 2 accounts. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 0):

We eventually resolved the issue by updating vorpX to the latest version and changing a setting in the vorpX ingame menu which is called **Direct Mode Show Original**